Find the longest substring with k repeated elements
The problem is to find the longest substring with k repeated elements, however k is the number of repeated elements e.g. if we have the string "ababcbb" and k=1, then the retrieved longest substrings are "babc" and "abcc" because in the first instance "b" is the repeated element and in the second instance "c" is the repeated element.  If k is two,the longest substring is "babccb", because "b" is repeated three times and "c" is repeated twice, that's what it's meant by "k is the number of repeated elements". In the final program, the string has to be read from a file.

def find_longest_substring(s, k):
    longest_substring = []
    current_substring = []
    current_counts = {}

    for char in s:
        if char in current_counts:
            current_counts[char] += 1
        else:
            current_counts[char] = 1

        current_substring.append(char)

        if max(current_counts.values()) > k:
            removed_char = current_substring.pop(0)
            current_counts[removed_char] -= 1
            if current_counts[removed_char] == 0:
                del current_counts[removed_char]

        if len(current_substring) > len(longest_substring):
            longest_substring = current_substring.copy()

    return longest_substring

def read_string_from_file(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as file:
        return file.read().strip()

def print_substring_and_frequency(substring):
    frequency = {}
    for char in substring:
        if char in frequency:
            frequency[char] += 1
        else:
            frequency[char] = 1

    print("Longest substring is", len(substring), ",", substring)
    print("Frequency:", [(char, freq) for char, freq in frequency.items()])

def main():
    filename = input("Enter the filename: ")
    k = int(input("Enter the value of k: "))
    s = read_string_from_file(filename)
    longest_substring = find_longest_substring(s, k)

    if longest_substring:
        print_substring_and_frequency(longest_substring)
    else:
        print("No valid substring found.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

This is the code I tried but it gives a wrong result.
The intended string for the code is:
jgigecbggjjihhefefkjhffbagdbckkbgkfgiekeefffjcbbikbidhjgedjdcabdkeccfecijajjgckihdhedaejjidaaddbifcebffafcbfibahjffgijbjchhceejihkidkbigkccbdbcechggeekhedjhahdhhgkihiacbgfifjbdjkeeccjaekhcibefajkeehcbeiihigekfcdihdbhjigbgfgdcckaddkffjiiddbdjdjdiekfkdiefhjjakjaijahgdabcdgghkkdggfdabhhgiehbfiiagghkkbjfbabkeejjacfbgbedejkhgkfjjccfkcacjcfehgagbbbghefghkdgehicbaajkbgiffachhkfcahhibkidjgbeccakbfcbkgibikahgajghahcgcjfageiddkcdhakdkjhfkibbijfbcceghagaggfhibfijefcijidhdcaegcgkiadhgedjegggajfeijkbbceejgddhjdkbghchfifghcabkkdfeiigjcbbbdfjbjakkgfjabifjdcediicebfefbjckkhccgbfbcijdjfckkgdhiegjkkkdckcjffcdabfjejjebgbajibgcaidcgiijjccigghbdicfgabhcafcbfceikhgijjdedagcgbbffidjjkbdhbceifjajbfakbfhdefhkbecijgedhcddidikckdhhcckafikkjkbidkdheckjdibfhjjfbfjkkdeckkkfcgicfjigaccikjgijbbhdddfaehkhibejaeadafhffiikgjfbhbachgdeaihcedebfajcbifaedihhgcjgkhfieiabfjhgfgcjdcfejedhhggbkikadkadieggjcjghbjadeafdjafbjhehacbbebcaekaafddegeecaacjfidgcjjbjahebagacjciggdfjfceifkbbcijjcgiijckejbbecaabdihfgifefgccjjdgcjkkbakfckddcgbbcfaegcajgkghfhbcacbfiihcgbkcckdjghjaeibhfhdifiigbhhekkfkacdfkafbfgbkdagkkgiidahidgebfgcjjabfdjcchbhedgagghkfhfbghcbjfkbjjhefcigiibfifkgfbddhgfdeiifacfghcfghifkcafekbjabcaidefaecaddjaiejcfafgbbaedhbiiigekbjdaigjgbfgbbcefehcagckcfcakegjichkceiihebiakhagcdggfgfbadhhkjehgekifaaddeafdbbfihchacakbdfhhbaggagkhbabhieiaehjkdccfgcfbfjdgddbigdjifijhdkbaheaajaefjhaddjfckkcekjkcbacgdibjhbdekhbdgfaccehabbgfehgidejgdefjagkfecjgcjakfgcaaeghiaffdghjebaagbaajfffjigekajhdeghfcdkdgjgjbbdddiabcajdgdkdihidefiikhhjigjhcdjebahjfhcbedjfkiiaiccjjdjbbabajhbkbfjjjiggehidgbefdfbddchdbfahedhahehhiakfcehifdbheejdkjfejhcebhjgbhbjfbbgbdffjbikfhjhgkcifjgcckcaadcbhagbihidfbidgfdbgihkceefccjgbfdbgbbgkhkejccbadfdjfbecbbfkcgcadbkfeejbjkdbjghhjehhdakjfjkfgbcfbgbjkjbhfafaabgekbcggakhfeidchhahhjghcjhefgehcaheghchdkggfffgifjgkidgfchijbgifffdebjcjechddijgbekhjjejjddkkgfdbjaechfgkfagbihhcbjhefejggkefcdkdeaekejdgdiddhcejfjhiiaakjjhjbbdeickijbfdccefahdjbggffekeeikgikbdafajdfiecijgbjihaadaigkegheejhaceghbidkjhgaakdejhigjdhdbciehbbfdeaaagebhbidhdjfkijhabggeccfbhheaaggegjeajadbddbecbjcdegekebdgjehidccaggagifagcjdaakachgdjejjjjeckiekjgcacdiffgbdadjfiabgdkfhkcdajhcbjbgaajihhebgbfeeibceddachgegagegfjdjbefcaafgabbhgjijjabbcfhjfakabbebkgjihdbbabfddhhggceadadhggiaefcegjabhcgcfkaidfkikfceejkbffgijbikabfgggfkcfbekdhkfcaidkddaddgbhcbifdhfkikbfihaicijhiidjefgijdgdhheakhcaijfjjbhchbiffcdkkhjdgbcedicjfbdfkbifjabkjiicgdccjahcfabgeecbfaefhbceacbkbbkeikaikcidgjegghhikibgcjgejhfaciikbfjfeejkkekbbkebghacfkbbijbfdijchgbdjbiedgiaafddbkihicjajifcekkefjhggbcikhjeackcgbgibfghjgdfadfbhhfibeibfcdjbdbcbjjciajehdhjciegghcfkhckgjbkgjdjjeahhjiiibhkbddfccckeakfcibkjbiakbecihbcgeafhjeaggkabcjeabgcgaaghdgijbaichideejaegeebhfiibdejicbedagdedfegbekjidbcihfhcjcggifcifaghhdbhdcbfcbafbacedibdecjdkigfhjkehajfhckgijdjdkecihkjbcfdgadgjjfiabcffkdejdicjkcfikieggbefakfchhceaigfbbhkcaigbefjafiajcbkdcdiceaighdaghhbgkkebgggachhdcbckhekhhbbihhdkjbefcifaajdffceakcceifaejgcbekgccgbjjhhgaeheggagkjgcjaeefbgfcfccficjbfgkjcfbikbbgdbjabjkcecbgccbdcckbbhjaabbdcadbchjgccdghjbjihageikcghbajdkkikghcdbfkejeiidggehgiddaijfccekjbfchfeckgkhkbhjdehhekajjjcibbageibfiihcidbdjifhaiffghgeibefjakekbbdaehagkdjfcchhgibdicicbcfkbbeiddjifghcjjefbbdkkiihjegikjgckcdhjahkjbkeidbbaikcigaekeffaekeahgehgcigdihdgeibdkicfkbbiefbckefihgdchbjkkhjfcbecgfjdicjekdicdbgjhbchkgkbdkifchegahjaiicccaadejaeijbdbjhagihecaejdefiaabhejiidjaedckhgkgdcggkhjgcjcijhhfjcaabhghcfgagfafdbbbfegeigefcidbcdcedhcibadgagbbibhdfjgjkfbgjddjgdgikdfkfjhdiaeihdbefjkhcgfiigcbdfkffidafijegahdkhjajkiehihfjcaadbkgdchjcjgaebehekchdgcfkgcijddckkgdiaibehdefkikghaggjcggbfijjkagfegedcdekegibihkhbakcicfbikegkjcfkhegddjfkkegkhgidibefgabdkcciabhgkbakghajfhfgkgjbacgkbkbffhgjhkihdhaicbhbdiagibajdebgjaddaffehcjjhjckjkcdfefejefjccjaejkfceadfjgdcagbbbahdfcbjgikadkahggkkfhajffibhdfdijbdcbbdkeehcgdhchabakfadbfddicahafjhjghfjdfkaciihjaefebeabdehigfeaggbdidkfekjegcdbbaggjhidhfckgfeedkbkdacjdfhgkjdebadeakekchaefcjkfahhgcahbhkcabjefkbdiihdbhhdigkhabbafifiececdkjecabbkgehkikckbeaaibeicbffjjhicahfbbaaccbbaeajdadcggfkifccgeckbiffgifdcabjhdjfakjchgcdkbekgekfeiibgieebheeckhefhijddjcecbchbhfdcjahabhcciedhacgdjbdgbajckbkiifdhkdbecjgkeeifjjfaebfgdfkjbkbahbbbihajbgbbaacjaafjddkdkadgfbfdjihhfabjhifkfiaekjggjiejjfahcgjddgabhjbahcgidbiccdhjhefikhbcgdafacejcaiiaefhdhgcegkggdhjcihieadkdjfkbfihbhdjadgkjcacafhcaaiajkejdgifiafgjbkbjadghjicjjkhjhicaifibibaeeafjgekfkcjbcaihihgbdbecichcbedbcfkabkgdifhegbcbcgjigaiakedkgdegeaaacakhgjbkeckjeggikiekhjhefcbdjecheffciffdikkcdbeiidkfkhdbdjbjchiigadikdegffgggdbffjbkbbakcfjejbhbadjiajiabfikkajkibgdfgikcafgdichjgbeaedecjjdjadfdabgbfbfgeddjhcabagigdjhieifdhjgbbgdabfeechgeikdghgccacgjeiehbjckgeghecchiddefighgcjijeeghddijabidfagjicgkechggfegkhccgagjdgbjkdcdkegchdbdeagibkjggjcheacagfcijefgbhcabjdhiffakcbdikahgfjgkdgjkckfbcdgbkdfkdakikiihheffcahcbaghegifafecjcgdcikjkkkccecheaakigdjkhafjaiikcdagghiickdgjgicjcghbfcdgdchahafkhfiiafajaccegkajjkfihaghchbdkhifffjikfkdgddcjadhbejfbfjhefdbfaihckdbkgaijdagkiabkidfdhbjkbakggiikhachggaacgbfaeccieakdbbcjghijjjfiachbgjkchiahkejikdkifjhecceehidgcgagfaccbkcagjkeaiciiagdbikgdfkcffjaiejfffbghfjjddcbaifehbjdhkgjfabdgdbffhagijaigekgfidebgiagjicgbcjgbjcbjdhehgchdiibeighckgihcgdaigaeihbgcgckgcdedkihgehheiaddgakhdhggfcecfafifehihicfdgajdjekbhadgegbbjjjieieffahdfdageigbcbjacihcfgbheffbegcgccfgcabbjdeaeicdcdjieibdfekbgdcacdkjhkkekceaiaakdffdihdkehkijjcbbijghkficdafjhcekejagcdkfeiffdkjhekiagbcfhgcfeefkkifefcikkehcifegachghedbfhahibeihfieikcgdeagcbjagjiggfgfekcijefeefbihhhbkakaiafkhaeekkeikfkfeaekhbkehhgcbcgecifkceeikhkcccfgdkgjgfjgbjckikacejcdiacagbgfgceafejcfeejifkiibfagjjbfcaaeccfffkgfkehjdagdbbkadcjjgibjibjejaiijcbijbbfabidgfbbjeciiegbgbhffkjcgfahfkfccdkbaihabfhcejeicdabkkjfcaibgajjaddahachjifddkjcfjkkhbaiabkiahfbiachchgbagabhkijkgjdbdkejchfiiiieijkjgjfkefcahcdcceijeehkhehfahbhfiiikejcbjeecjgejbagkdbkbibficbahiddafgibjkgdedfbaababhghghbdiacbgcifchdhicgfbbbefbdfjfbjaagbikfgjdcjebdgeicffdbhaheihcddcahdaidjahdahcgihgcgbdgcbefcfgeahaebaecbicaeibccjjbcegkafaaffekgaidefghfbdfjfabaddbeceebdgdbdjjgeafkkbijdajcefbkjkcjjfaigkkaahjjdekdcfjijgfifkijaekgbggahkebccgahfecddccdedejfkfgakjjfafkjjbddaadjjhkcjigagedhkikgeacickebfaedebgigbajcggcgceaffkjgicjjcagbdbgeaeckikdiickdhkfdkhcdfddcbbecjigeejdbajikikficajihkfdfcfeafjfjchdibeghfcfaifkekfdehfcfhjabajbjegikihahcjekfgddajgccaaffjdbekhkfikfefbiidjaakaaiabjadbdcgddekbecfakkjhchjafihidiahcgefgcdheegahjjfhaeaabcbfeakbiiejgefijcjfdgjfjjjdkddighiehihckddchdbchhecjckbbigbhejcdafhhajghdjifadhbggbjiahjgjcaacehjeejceghebbdbhhiifeijkkkfakebhahhhchbbiheacgjickbfgdijkkebkfafkcejbkegkgeafdfegiakfegbbkcdihejckdbfgkdcifcccdkihgeffcabbdaaagbajefjgfecdgecbdkdbheiidhjjckbafdhjccedjchbahkeiaikakgfcaaabibhdgafbhghbekefibbhdjkfeejbfhdkbaaheikakhfghcbicjgiebcicefbciajhjdifibcgbdkhfbhhbicgaacajedfhdcjaehjjfgfkjiajdghhhbbhkfbfffjfcegdcegdggdbhhecgfffggekdfjfieihfkcghkaahbhdhiejahfeihgeicjbkekegbebbgfkakccjdhicjgkcdcbacfjkgajhbhaabbghfjceiaccfeceegbghkcdbfebhjkdkfgdekgfceakjjhgjadeegcejkbgffkcbheigccfadjcdjjfejfhbgebkbggdabfcajacaegffecggikgihjjidejbjkffhhgaccdacigdgjbkdgiigjajiigdfdhiggcggdaggckehbjbhijbbfeeacgkaehigiiiigagggckbadjhkbjahfehihhbafbbjiagejfaecahfhdikaajkbeabbbjfgiajjjfjakddchfhbkjkgekjhbabaiheehcaifafideeigcebgjeidfdijfcfeggcgaaejgjhgfdgfbbhejchfdkgeekhhckieagabgiffjdahfkchibgagcifdjffhbcihcehidgkhbbakdacgiefhgagcibeghjbcdkdifbkjgehgaaigdidfaacekkiigjkdcdbbggjhakkbickkajkgchjjikdkbigddjadhbchiefjeaihkibbcgdegiajbbbfehjhbbefakdebdfecjidhjdigfekdfdiekdhiddhceackcihfafajdaaaddhafdkejdegccjfebhhkehgekdcjkbhbddaiekgiachiaafaefhbfabjkchghkkcjghacidhdkddjkbcgihhgckbbhfebaiighggehgkgkbfkkejgficbgbhfdcckhhihijdiiebhdggkhbakkadgeibcidkafjijjedfgajcdhhhaeiejchjecfifdchbkkjbdeecfeaaejeeibabhckdgejjjgkckekhicfchbkcickhicejiaifaikjhikghkaaghfikbgaefidaakddihdachceicbchbebiggaahgjbaekbbfefibchgdjfkjcahfhjkiefjjicfeegjdfhfakacijcaakchdfjecigcigihkjdkgabjfbfcijgbbiidkkddefiijgjjbjcdihbidfihicjibkkhggcifckchdffebhgdijbbdfebiaebiafchcaiedgihbceagahbgkbkbdcghaaakhhcighgchegaeddfaakbgciadhiaejeigfhcdjacajjfcfahhbeajjbfibiaibjddiihddbeicjbdacfdjidjbgdahfjagefgakcidfghahjgibhdkcgdijcdaeecjgbikijfhkijbffiiididgbehbfhcbkedbhhkhhbkheeajhfeafagigkhahhgjkcffcfhjbkbehefeefbkfjfacdhjkabhkhccefddbheajheheeihegiiffiiiedidcicekeccddidhcjjdddfekfjcibekkfgiicjihfkbhhkcjjciakjccgkhjcaahkdfebeebcjdjkbijcffcjahdjgijkgadagbkfebgcfecfigkdeekaefhfeighedhkcaechhiaddeijagaikkkjfdfekigckgkfahdfdigdffaefbkfhjebdedibafcjckjbcihhddgdbjjciffedfcjadfijdhgfdicbjijeiabhfkkhkbckjeggehfhdbeaahabhgifackiagijifahiffgkjicjidjkjjegcfcghjgeefbijagfbbiehjedfigekadfehebifjhjfifaecikkijckhgcajihhhaejkdggkifffiicejbbdgggffccdehhcehjijieiiadkhiiccbhacdafgdejgicigagcbkfckjdjjdbcicahfeaakedaiiihdkbfdjffcjfiajfjhkadghjihccbfckadjgkiibgdaheaaehdjjhaidhjkeeaiedfkghajejgehbakkadgidcbdehejakegehfbhgaifkiageakidbekcgjcfhjdhicbbhjhgbhbbkfhhcakccgbcagieabeajcfcbaifgjfgaffegjjadkfbhdejchkjeaedhachcehgbefhaacfijaefjgfhccjkjeidgcfgceekejbdcgacgfdcaeechkfcbahcbgfcdajikjafkaekekfejhggjeagidekiceefbeiieffafecjccefdcddbgabbhghekkgbjhkjibkdecgcbbceccadcjjhgacgifhbdjadhjkkdbkhbegkbhibfacfgdjajcjhkjagbaaghjafcdghabccccehchjkgfkkkdjjakffkeihjhjdkabdchbkgefkfbceccdjikdcjabaedfajfjabkajdekfhiaaaejajfeefkhbjgfdebfbgddahieejhedfcjfjhbckdkgdcegidaddechadbcekkjihchahagafgbgacfebdkhadicheidfafcgkjdkkhgkebhfkjagkhgjigkifjaddgkhajbdibgcicdekbjjjihfficfjecdiafkhgbacajhehgjagcadjdcgjidjabgeekjebbihcjkakhkgbifhdcbabjjkhafggekehihjdkchbkdgcchefeccgfckbhhdekhcbbdiidhahihjeakjjiadijadihjkedcdjjiabkiecceacagjicjjgdgcfhjhfjgfkdekjcjcjdkkijifegkiggjcbecjbkjfhcghfacfaciagakejaickkkideihchkadjeihhidghiakakfbfgfagejekkaabkkdedfgbjbkdgedbjgfgeabkjjffgdajgbkbfjaeihhbeakeicajijcafaggakdghgigeabegcihejfbejekjhceikghhahjkjbcjbighjeehdjgebbdkgiafciecgbebiiajccafhciigeefchacgigadhbedbgaakcfbhbibjfeekfahdidbhjjdafekbdgadadjjchiicffhbdiheadghdechkdgjgkhdcciibigcgkfeccjbhhkdgbkgdjaeeigchhbdkeeeckcbhfjaafjaiaajacebdagfcbfdecaebbbedihicidfhjkieakffbikiaaicjebjjeajkjbaeekgjhbabafbcicgbdighabgjciachbjfajddaedkejfaeecdgkhhkhdahfkabdjijiejgkfhjefebckkgbchkhghabhecdekgekhfikghebccbbijahbiakibddjggahchfdeafbgdhegkhjakaffhgickjhfhcfkhcaakafbifdbhbgbcjacck

the intended result for k=3 is k=3,  longest substring is 22, ['j', 'j', 'g', 'i', 'b', 'j', 'i', 'b', 'j', 'e', 'j', 'a', 'i', 'i', 'j', 'c', 'b', 'i', 'j', 'b', 'b', 'f'] with the frequency [('i', 5), ('b', 5), ('j', 7)]
                                              ['d', 'd', 'd', 'i', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'j', 'd', 'g', 'd', 'k', 'd', 'i', 'h', 'i', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'i', 'i'] with the frequency [('i', 5), ('a', 2), ('d', 7)]

                                              

['d', 'f', 'k', 'c', 'f', 'f', 'j', 'a', 'i', 'e', 'j', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'b', 'g', 'h', 'f', 'j', 'j', 'd', 'd'] with the frequency [('j', 4), ('d', 3), ('f', 7)]

the answer I get is Longest substring is 32 ,
 ['b', 'a', 'f', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'e', 'd', 'i', 'b', 'd', 'e', 'c', 'j', 'd', 'k', 'i', 'g', 'f', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'e', 'h', 'a', 'j', 'f', 'h', 'c', 'k', 'g', 'i']

Frequency:
 [('b', 3), ('a', 3), ('f', 3), ('c', 3), ('e', 3), ('d', 3), ('i', 3), ('j', 3), ('k', 3), ('g', 2), ('h', 3)]


Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include the sample,  expected results and the actual results.

So the length of the longest substring is 22, but yours is 32. Do you know why your answer is wrong, or do you not know and you're asking here to clarify what the question is asking for?

I understand what the question is asking for however I have no idea why my answer is wrong. If I had to guess, it's because my approach is wrong, however if I knew how to do it correctly, I wouldn't be posting it here.

Please fix the example, "abcc" isn't even a substring at all.

You can refine your sliding window approach by accurately maintaining a count of how many characters have occurrences that match or exceed 'k'. This requires adjusting the sliding window size based on whether this condition is met or not.
Here is your your code with detailed comments to help you understand the necessary adjustments:
def find_longest_substring(s, k):
    if k == 0:
        return ""  # Special case, if k is 0, return empty string

    n = len(s)
    max_len = 0
    longest_substrings = []

    # Try to find the longest substring for every possible starting character
    for start in range(n):
        counts = {}
        freq = {}
        max_char_freq = 0

        # Sliding window from start
        for end in range(start, n):
            char = s[end]
            if char in counts:
                counts[char] += 1
            else:
                counts[char] = 1
            
            # Frequency of the character count
            if counts[char] in freq:
                freq[counts[char]] += 1
            else:
                freq[counts[char]] = 1

            # Maintain max_char_freq which tracks the number of chars meeting the k requirement
            if counts[char] == k:
                max_char_freq += 1

            # Check if we have exactly 'k' distinct characters all with frequencies >= k
            if max_char_freq == k:
                current_len = end - start + 1
                if current_len > max_len:
                    max_len = current_len
                    longest_substrings = [s[start:end+1]]
                elif current_len == max_len:
                    longest_substrings.append(s[start:end+1])

            # Break early if the number of possible characters with freq >= k exceeds
            if max_char_freq > k:
                break

    return longest_substrings, max_len

This implementation modifies how the sliding window adjusts based on the count of characters that meet the repetition requirement (k). It now returns all such substrings of the maximum length where k characters are repeated at least k times. Additionally, it better handles multiple substrings of equal length meeting the criteria.
here is full code:
def find_longest_substring(s, k):
    if k == 0:
        return ""  # Special case, if k is 0, return empty string

    n = len(s)
    max_len = 0
    longest_substrings = []

    # We try to find the longest substring for every possible starting character
    for start in range(n):
        counts = {}
        freq = {}
        max_char_freq = 0

        # Sliding window from start
        for end in range(start, n):
            char = s[end]
            if char in counts:
                counts[char] += 1
            else:
                counts[char] = 1
            
            # Frequency of the character count
            if counts[char] in freq:
                freq[counts[char]] += 1
            else:
                freq[counts[char]] = 1

            # Maintain max_char_freq which tracks the number of chars meeting the k requirement
            if counts[char] == k:
                max_char_freq += 1

            # Check if we have exactly 'k' distinct characters all with frequencies >= k
            if max_char_freq == k:
                current_len = end - start + 1
                if current_len > max_len:
                    max_len = current_len
                    longest_substrings = [s[start:end+1]]
                elif current_len == max_len:
                    longest_substrings.append(s[start:end+1])

            # Breaking out early if the number of possible characters with freq >= k exceeds
            if max_char_freq > k:
                break

    return longest_substrings, max_len

def read_string_from_file(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as file:
        return file.read().strip()

def print_substrings_and_frequencies(substrings):
    print(f"Longest substrings of length {len(substrings[0])} with exactly k repeated elements:")
    for substring in substrings:
        frequency = {}
        for char in substring:
            if char in frequency:
                frequency[char] += 1
            else:
                frequency[char] = 1
        print(f"Substring: {substring}")
        print("Frequency:", [(char, freq) for char, freq in frequency.items()])

def main():
    filename = input("Enter the filename: ")
    k = int(input("Enter the value of k: "))
    s = read_string_from_file(filename)
    longest_substrings, max_len = find_longest_substring(s, k)

    if longest_substrings:
        print_substrings_and_frequencies(longest_substrings)
    else:
        print("No valid substring found.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


When I used this code it not still giving the correct answer for when k=3 and k=4
This is what it is supposed to look like
k=3,  longest substring is 22, ['j', 'j', 'g', 'i', 'b', 'j', 'i', 'b', 'j', 'e', 'j', 'a', 'i', 'i', 'j', 'c', 'b', 'i', 'j', 'b', 'b', 'f'] with the frequency [('i', 5), ('b', 5), ('j', 7)]
['d', 'd', 'd', 'i', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'j', 'd', 'g', 'd', 'k', 'd', 'i', 'h', 'i', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'i', 'i'] with the frequency [('i', 5), ('a', 2), ('d', 7)]
                                          ['d', 'f', 'k', 'c', 'f', 'f', 'j', 'a', 'i', 'e', 'j', 'f', 'f', 'f', 'b', 'g', 'h', 'f', 'j', 'j', 'd', 'd'] with the frequency [('j', 4), ('d', 3), ('f', 7)]

k=4,  longest substring is 29, ['i', 'g', 'd', 'g', 'j', 'b', 'k', 'd', 'g', 'i', 'i', 'g', 'j', 'a', 'j', 'i', 'i', 'g', 'd', 'f', 'd', 'h', 'i', 'g', 'g', 'c', 'g', 'g', 'd'] with the frequency [('i', 6), ('g', 9), ('j', 3), ('d', 5)]

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
